# When posting the JsonArray in retrofit automatically add some okhttp content in json

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit2

I need some help to pass the jsonarray in retrofit post method in Android.
I have create one pojo class `List<ReportList>` when I call the api that time i convert this pojo class into JSONArray using Gson() like this

```
JsonArray myCustomArray = new Gson().toJsonTree(ReportsArray).getAsJsonArray();
```

and than I post this jsonArray into retrofit post method like this

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST(midURL)
Call<Json> ReportsManagement(@Field(fClass) String classs,
                                    @Field(fMethod) String method,
                                    @Field(fType) String type,
                                    @Field(fUserID) String userID,
                                    @Field(fDate) String Date,
                                    @Field(fReportsArray) String ReportsArray,
                                    @Field(fEntryByUser) String EntryByUser);
```

Now when I call the api that time I have show some issue in passing the json data in api in android studio logcat.

> class=crud&method=ReportsManagement&Type=ADD&UserID=8&Date=2018-06-08&ReportsArray=[{"Date":"08-06-2018","IV1":"","IV10":"","IV11":"","IV12":"","IV13":"","IV14":"","IV15":"","IV16":"","IV17":"","IV18":"","IV19":"","IV2":"","IV20":"","IV21":"","IV22":"","IV23":"","IV24":"","IV25":"","IV26":"","IV3":"","IV4":"","IV5":"","IV6":"","IV7":"","IV8":"","IV9":"","IVF":""},{"Date":"08-06-2018","FIO2":"","IV1":"","IV10"**%06-08 08:13:07.461 23291-23476/com.abc D/OkHttp:3A**"","IV11":"","IV12":"","IV13":"","IV14":"","IV15":"","IV16":"","IV17":"","IV18":"","IV19":"","IV2":"","IV20":"","IV21":"","IV22":"","IV23":"","IV24":"","IV25":"","IV26":"","IV3":"","IV4":"","IV5":"","IV6":"","IV7":"","IV8":"","IV9":"","IVF":""}]
>
> Error in json :**%06-08 08:13:07.461 23291-23476/com.abc D/OkHttp:3A**

Comment: this looks like mixed logs. Don't worry about it

Comment: But for this mixed logs i did't get the correct data from mysql side. when i remove this mixed logs data and send the data in api than i get the correct data at mysql side. so that's via i need to solve this issue.

Comment: if you going to post json, you should use ```@Body``` annotation for post  instead of ```@Field```

Comment: how do you go from `myCustomArray` to the `ReportsArray` string?

Comment: Hmm i go from this myCustomArray = new Gson().toJsonTree(ReportsArray).getAsJsonArray();
String jsonProfile = new Gson().toJson(myCustomArray); i have pass the record in post method so at the server side is get the request parameter as string and is convert into jsonArray and than save data in database.